# What is the error in this code for transmitting from PHP an array to an API?

Tags: php, json, wordpress, gravity-forms-plugin

Hello everyone and thank you to those who will answer me.
I am working on a Plugin in Wordpress that where to take data from a form made with Gravity Form and send it to a CRM.
Two APIs are needed to write the data, one with the Token for authorization and one for the actual input.
I can take the Token quietly, take the field data on Gravity Form and put it into an Array.
However, when I try to invoke the API for entry, it returns a strange error that I honestly can't find by searching the net

```
"error":{"httpStatusCode":400, "message": "Expected end of string, but instead reached end of data. Path: $.name | LineNumber: 2 | BytePositionInLine: 7.", "messageType": "Error"}, "response":null}
```

I report the code I am using taken by your good colleagues

```
add_filter( 'gform_after_submission', 'registrazone', 10, 2 );

function registrazone ( $entry, $form) {
     #FIXME: Hardcoded url
$url2 = 'https://gogogogo.com/api/load';

#Assumption: The params below have already been verified.
$topup_data2 = array("accept"        =>      "text/plain",
                     "token"         =>      $token);
                    

#JSON encode the params
$topup_str2   = json_encode($topup_data2);

#Curl init
$ch2 = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch2, CURLOPT_URL, $url2);
curl_setopt($ch2, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
        'Content-Type: application/json',
        'Content-Length: '.strlen($topup_str2)
    )
);  

$actual_link = "http://$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]";
$note = "Contatto da pagina " . $actual_link;
$valid_cellulare_b = rgar( $entry, '7' );

#I use JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK but thinks that error is for not "" so use strval
$valid_cellulare_a = strval( $valid_cellulare_b ); 

$payload = json_encode( array( 'nome' => rgar( $entry, '3.3' ),
                                'cellulare'=> $valid_cellulare_a,
                                'email' => rgar( $entry, '5' ), 
                                'nota' => $note,
                                'cognome' => rgar( $entry, '3.6' ),                                                               
                                'provinciaDomicilio' => rgar( $entry, '9' ),
                            ), 
                            JSON_PRETTY_PRINT | JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES
                      );
echo "<pre>$payload</pre>";
curl_setopt($ch2, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $payload);
# Return response instead of printing.
curl_setopt($ch2, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
# Send request.
$result2 = curl_exec($ch2);
curl_close($ch2);
# Print response.
echo "<pre>$result2</pre>";

}
```

the array payload returns this pattern

```
{
    "nome": "Joan",
    "cellulare": "349XXXXXXX",
    "email": "info@XXXXXX.com",
    "nota": "Contact from page https://gogogogogogo.com",
    "cognome": "Trello",
    "provinciaDomicilio": "GG"
}
```

The error

```
{"error":{"httpStatusCode":400,"message":"Expected end of string, but instead reached end of data. Path: $.nome | LineNumber: 2 | BytePositionInLine: 7.","messageType":"Error"},"response":null}
```

Comment: you are setting `content-length` header from different string than actual data sent

Comment: You did try without `JSON_PRETTY_PRINT | JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES`, right? @Gia